# WP Rest API как получить thumbnail к постам?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, rest

Доброго времени суток, есть задача, получить все посты аяксом и отобразить, с последним проблем нету, а вот с получением проблемы, работаю с api wp через backbone.js client и что-то не могу понять две вещи

1. Как получить посты из определённой категории?
2. Как получить thumbnail поста?
3. Как получить description поста?

Да, обещал 2 вопроса, написал 3) на самом деле последний не обязательно, но интересно было бы узнать. На developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/, пол часа провел в поисках и ничего не смог найти по интересующим вопросам.

```
// текущий код, где я получаю посты
new wp.api.collections.Posts().fetch().done(function(){/* обработка данных после загрузки */});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=POST_ID
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]